# How do I delete songs in iTunes that have an exclamation mark?

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

I have a bunch of files that I moved or deleted in Finder, and now iTunes shows exclamation marks. I would like to delete these from iTunes and from iTunes Match / iCloud. How do I do that, using free software?

One can't sort by the exclamation mark in iTunes, and Super Remove Dead Tracks costs money.

This is regarding iTunes 11 on Mavericks.

Comment: $1.99 is not money this days. And you can try it for free for 10 days.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it, but I'm not willing to pay for what I think should be basic functionality in iTunes. In any case, thanks for trying to help.